# Follow user gives 401 forbidden with Swift SoundcloudSDK - What am I missing here?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, soundcloud

Im using the soundcloudSDk for swift (https://github.com/delannoyk/SoundcloudSDK).

Im trying to make a user follow another user but can't seem to get it working. I get the error message "Soundcloud.SoundcloudError.Forbidden" when trying to follow another user. Am I missing something?

Here is my code

```
    Soundcloud.clientIdentifier = "my identifier"
    Soundcloud.clientSecret  = "my secret"
    Soundcloud.redirectURI = "my redirect uri"


    Session.login(self) { (session: SimpleAPIResponse<Session>) in


        var SCSession = Soundcloud.session
        //Im getting a session if I'm printing it out
        //SCSession Optional(<Soundcloud.Session: 0x7fe272d88af0>)

        SCSession?.refreshSession({ (refreshedSession: SimpleAPIResponse<Session>) in

            SCSession?.me({ (user: SimpleAPIResponse<User>) in

                //Im getting my user if printing the result so it looks like I'm actually getting the session so I'm able to make private calls.

                //Here I'm trying to follow a random user and this is when it stops working
                user.response.result?.follow(183643398, completion: { (answer: SimpleAPIResponse<Bool>) in
                    print("Followed user", answer.response.isSuccessful)
                    print("Followed user", answer.response.error)
                    print("Followed user", answer.response.result)
                })


            })
        })

   }
```

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Would you mind creating a title that contains *any* information? All of the buzzwords are already in the tags and have absolutely no value in the title.

Comment: Changed the title a bit